# Excel VBA Worksheet change event triggers with multiple cell copy and paste

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working with a worksheet change event procedure to update a change log when the cell value of a cell in a range is altered. Currently the procedure works fine for single cell entry and vertical pasting of data. For instance pasting a horizontal selection of cells into the range triggers the event correctly.

My problem is that the change event also triggers when a range of cells are pasted over the range of the change event and straddles the columns either side. For instance if a user was to paste a range of cells into the document that spanned AN47:AR47 the change event triggers. can this be stopped? Note I cant use the option of "If Target.Cells.count > 1 Then end sub" as I want the event to trigger when a single column of data is pasted into the range, such as AP46:AP56 etc

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim RNG1 As Range
Dim RNG2 As Range
Set RNG1 = Sheet8.Range("$AP$46:$AP$145")
Set RNG2 = Sheet8.Range("$BA$46:$BA$145")

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False                    (make it faster)
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 If Not Intersect(Target, Union(RNG1, RNG2)) Is Nothing Then
 If Target.Cells.count > 1 Then
    TgValue = extractData(Target)
 Else
    TgValue = Array(Array(Target.Value, Target.Address(0, 0)))  'put the target range in an array (or as a string for a single cell)
    boolOne = True
 End If
etc etc
end sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave the sub if the target has more than one column

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
```